# Anyone else having an issue seeing padding in Computed Chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools, computed-properties

Not sure if this is a bug or something on my end, but Chrome dev tools appear to have stopped showing some Computed properties, specifically padding.

I looked at my settings and all seemed normal. It also seems to work in other browsers' dev tools (Safari, Firefox).

I sent an inquiry to Chrome/Google but doubt I'll hear back. Wondering if anyone else is seeing this or it's something I'm doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: https://crbug.com/1383735

Comment: Having the same issue 3 months later....

Comment: yep, same here looks like a chrome version has caused the issue, anyone else has got more updates on this?  padding: 0 doesn't seem to work